# Android Emulator very slow in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017, parallels, macbookpro-touch-bar

Running Visual Studio 2017 with latest updates in Parallels 14 with latest updates. I have a 2018 MBP with 16 GB RAM, 2.6 i7, 512 GB SSD. I have given 8 GB to Parallels.

In Parallels I have "Enabled nested virtualization" and "Adaptive Hypervisor" (see picture below).

I have confirmed in Windows 10 that I am running Hyper-V.

When I run the most minimal Xamarin.Forms I am getting wildly inconsistent build times, from a low of 40 seconds [one time] to 4 minutes to never completed. Cannot correlate with any different Android Virtual devices and API levels, whether it is ARM or x86 architecture, etc. I have tried using a real Android device but it never appears in VS 2017 (I have set debugging on in the device and downloaded the driver and I can see it in my PC).

Is it possible to develop in Xamarin in VS 2017 on a Mac in emulation? If so, what can I do to get stable, timely Android emulation?

Thanks,

Bryan

[image]

Comment: Do not run the Emulator within the VM and thus nested visualization is not needed (which is **very slow** w/ Google's Android emulator), run it macOS and connect to it from Visual Studio that is running in your VM. The build times might be due t page swapping as 8gb is not much memory when you include Windows, VS and a running AVD. You can review the stats in Activity Monitor to confirm.

Comment: try [Windows Hypervisor Platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?tabs=vswin&pivots=windows#accelerating-with-hyper-v) and to get the phone working, make sure the USB driver is installed via Andoird SDK Manager and the device is attached to the VM.